# How to fetch value from array if key "Ans" is true in postman?

Tags: json, postman

```
{
  "errorMessage": null,
  "status": null,
  "products": {
    "Test1": {
      "label1": "Testing",
      "duration": [
        {
          "Value": "987654",
          "Ans": "True"
        },
        {
          "Value": "987159",
          "Ans": "False"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Test2": {
      "label1": "Testing",
      "duration": [
        {
          "Value": "987654",
          "Ans": "True"
        },
        {
          "Value": "987159",
          "Ans": "False"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to fetch the value for key "value" if "Ans" is true, and save it in environment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
const productList = Object.values(res.products);
const valueAns = [];
productList.forEach((e) => {
    e.duration.forEach((i) => {
        if (i.Ans === "True") {
            valueAns.push(i.Value);
        }
    });
});
pm.environment.set("valueAns", valueAns);

console.log(valueAns);
//[ '987654', '987654' ]
```